# Why add display in CSS animation make item a bit transparent?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I created a css animation from opacity 1 to 0. Inside, I use display block to none at the last frame to remove item. Here is the keyframe :

```
@keyframes hide {
          0%{            
            opacity: 100%;
            display: block;
          }
          72%{
            opacity: 100%;
            display: block;
          }
          99%{ 
            opacity: 0%;
            display: block;
          }
          100%{ 
            opacity: 0%;
            display: none;
          }
        }
```

And we can see what is behind at the beginning (Windows logo) [image]

When I put 100% or remove Opacity, the bug is still there. Even if I had 30s animation duration, it's visible at start. But When I remove display,visibility or even z-index, it's gone and we can't see throught anymore

[image]

Do you know why this happen ? Is this because display can't be animated and it create a bug ?